# How can I find IP of consumer that dequed a message from ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have `ActiveMQ` server (with Camel deployed on it) from which consumers on different machines read messages.

I can see via Web interface that messages are enqueued on and dequeued from `ActiveMQ` but I don't know where are they landing.

How can I find `IP` of consumer that dequed a message from `ActiveMQ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I looked at `conf/camel.xml` and found were messages are routed.